# Detect c# 6 features with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

Is there a way to detect a c# 6 feature with a roslyn diagnostic analyzer?

I have a solution that links in some files from a project that cannot use c#6 features, so I want to make that an error just for those files. 
To be clear - I cannot set the whole project to c#5, only some files are off limits.

I can try and catch specific features, but it's cumbersome and was wondering if there is a faster way?

Comment: As an alternative that is likely much easier to implement: simply run a build using a C#5 compiler on that project as part of your build process. Whether that's a custom build event, or as part of your CI is up to you.

Comment: @Rob I really think thats the way to go right here.

Comment: @Rob I only have some files linked in that project from another one, those should not use these features. The rest could use them.

Comment: @RobertIvanc Yes - I understand :). However, that project (the one that does not allow C#6) can be built as a separate process using a C#5 compiler. For example: You would build the *entire* solution using a C#6 compiler. You then kick off a secondary build which compiles those specific projects with a C#5 compiler. If the second build fails, but the first passes - it means you have C#6 code in those projects

Comment: @Rob Ah, I understand now! I'd still like an analyzer based solution so that it notifies developers as soon as they type and it wouldn't demand another build. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Walker for detecting C# 6 syntax features:

```
public class CSharp6FeaturesWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    public bool CSharp6Features { get; private set; }

    public CSharp6FeatureWalker()
    {
    }

    public override void VisitPropertyDeclaration(PropertyDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        if (node.ExpressionBody != null)
        {
            CSharp6Features = true;
        }
        else if (node.Initializer != null)
        {
            CSharp6Features = true;
        }
        base.VisitPropertyDeclaration(node);
    }

    public override void VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        if (node.ExpressionBody != null)
        {
            CSharp6Features = true;
        }
        base.VisitMethodDeclaration(node);
    }

    public override void VisitOperatorDeclaration(OperatorDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        if (node.ExpressionBody != null)
        {
            CSharp6Features = true;
        }
        base.VisitOperatorDeclaration(node);
    }

    public override void VisitConversionOperatorDeclaration(ConversionOperatorDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        if (node.ExpressionBody != null)
        {
            CSharp6Features = true;
        }
        base.VisitConversionOperatorDeclaration(node);
    }

    public override void VisitIndexerDeclaration(IndexerDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        if (node.ExpressionBody != null)
        {
            CSharp6Features = true;
        }
        base.VisitIndexerDeclaration(node);
    }

    public override void VisitConditionalAccessExpression(ConditionalAccessExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        CSharp6Features = true;
        base.VisitConditionalAccessExpression(node);
    }

    public override void VisitInterpolatedStringExpression(InterpolatedStringExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        CSharp6Features = true;
        base.VisitInterpolatedStringExpression(node);
    }

    public override void VisitCatchFilterClause(CatchFilterClauseSyntax node)
    {
        CSharp6Features = true;
        base.VisitCatchFilterClause(node);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to detect whether the file written on 6 version or not based only on syntax checks because of some features are content-depended such as `nameof` operator (it can be both special or usual method)

For testing C# 6 features you can use [this file](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/csharp/examples/AllInOne.cs#L710) from ANTLR grammars repository.

Comment: thank you, this seems to be the best way to go about it!

Comment: You already named `nameof()` as a hurdle so I'd add "using static", "Dictionary initializers", `await` within `catch` and `finally` blocks, and maybe something else I have forgotten. It should definitely be noted that the solution as presented only covers the basics (though admittedly: they're the most common usages). You can expand on this with most of these other changes as well though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to go about this is to use the advanced build options.  Go to your project properties and select the "Build" tab.  On the bottom-right of that tab (you may have to scroll down) you should see an "Advanced" button.  Click that and you'll get this dialog:

[image: Advanced Options]

As you see, you can change the language level for your particular project to be C# 5.0.  Once you do that, and you try to use, say, string interpolation, you'll be prompted with an error:

[image]

Comment: I guess I was not very clear (it is a very strange project) - only some files from within a project should not use c#6 features, not the whole project, so this will not work. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @RobertIvanc, but I don't understand why you don't create a separate project for those particular files.  Seems like exactly the correct use-case for project segragation.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like your question is "these particular files are linked into another project that can't use C# 6." Then mark that other project as not being able to use C# 6...?