# Roslyn / .NET Compiler Platform get current project C# language version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I'm writing a simple code refactoring with Roslyn that would introduce throwing `ArgumentNullException` exceptions if a parameter is null, like this:

```
if (parameter == null)
  throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter");
_parameter = parameter;
```

Now, for C# 6 this can be made more elegant (readable? type-safe?, whatever) using the `nameof` operator. And from C# 7, I can use the throw expressions as well :

```
_parameter = parameter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter));
```

But, obviously, this does not compile if the language version of the project is not set up to support C# 6 / C# 7 or whatever language version the feature requests.

Given this context, my question is simple. Is there a way to determine the current language version with Roslyn, so I can decide at generation-time which code snippet to suggest? Or is there any other way to detect if a feature is supported in the current C# project?

Comment: Why not just keep what you currently have?  You still have to have it as a fallback if the language is not of the right version, so just keep it if you anticipate needing lower language support

Comment: @maccettura because the OP wants to create an *analyzer* for people that don't want it the old way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341634/detect-c-sharp-6-features-with-roslyn

Comment: According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10147) you could use the [CSharpOptions.LanguageVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpparseoptions.languageversion?view=roslyn-dotnet#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_CSharp_CSharpParseOptions_LanguageVersion) property through `SyntaxTree.ParseOptions.LanguageVerson`. The feature detection API wasn't public at least back in 2016

Comment: *Unfortunately*, [LanguageVersion](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/LanguageVersion.cs) contains the same entries as the build page, including `Default` and `Latest` which doesn't say anything about the actual version. You *could* play dirty and call [IsFeatureEnabled](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/CSharpParseOptions.cs#L203) using Reflection but yuck

Comment: And yet, at least one [Roslyn Analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/master/src/Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers/CSharp/Maintainability/CSharpUseNameofInPlaceOfString.cs) uses the `ParseOptions` class

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for all the research you've done, this gave me some good stating points. And if it's good enough for MS, it's good enough for me. Unfortunately I don't think `ParseOptions` is only available in diagnostic analyzers, not refactoring providers...